# Automatically add the "www" subdomain for my webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, url-rewriting

How can I set Tomcat to automatically redirect to "www"?
I want that if a user enters my domain like:

mydomain.com

he will be redirected to: www.mydomain.com

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Apache, simple do (on htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

This way you make sure anything that is not using www starts using

**UPDATE**
As you mentioned you don't have apache, I remembered I used [this](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) about a year ago. It does pretty much the same as mod_rewrite, and is fully supported by Tomcat. I used it with resin though, but I know it works the same way.

Greatest thing about it, is that it also runs on "mod_rewrite style", as you can see [here](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html). The only reason why I didn't continue using it, is because it will end up doing it at a server level, as opposed to a webserver level. Meaning it will call the JVM to interpret the redirect.

It works the same way though, and as mentioned before, can sue exactly the same thing you'd use on Apache.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer.
I know how it is done with Apache. Unfortunately, I don't have Apache, only Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. Minor tweak to the RewriteRule to avoid a double / on the redirected URL: `RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 6):

The [tuckey url rewrite filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) can be used like this to do the proper redirection:

```
<rule>
  <name>Canonical Hostnames</name>
  <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www.mydomain.com</condition>
  <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="redirect" last="true">http://www.mydomain.com/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

wwwizer.com offers free naked domain redirect http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect

Point your naked domain like mysite.com to their IP, and they'll do a 301 redirect to www.mysite.com

Using a 301 redirect is the recommended way for SEO optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), you can also use the following rule:

```xml
<rule>
    <condition type="header" name="host" operator="equal">^[^.]+[.][^.]+$</condition>
    <from>^/.*</from>
    <to qsappend="true" type="redirect" last="true">${replaceFirst:%{request-url}://://www.}</to>
</rule>
```

This one is quite interesting, since nothing is hardcoded: it works for any domain and keeps port number and protocol.

Functions seem to be implemented since v3.1.

---

There is a known issue with the `qsappend` attribute: https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=116. You need to implement the fix specified on the link.

Simply create the package `org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite` in your webapp, create the class `NormalRule` in it, and copy/paste the content of the following class: http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/tuckey/web/filters/urlrewrite/NormalRule.java.